# Jquery - create a div and other child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to make a comment section for my site. After a comment has been posted I would like to show it immediately instead of being forced to reload the page. So I need to somehow be able to create div and other elements and later fill them with the relevant data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".commentAnswer").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {

            var commentData = { Value: ($(input).attr("data-answerId")),
                Description: ($(input).attr("value"))
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SubmitComment", "Home")',
                data: JSON.stringify(commentData),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //create elements.

                }
            });

        }

    });
```

This the block I want to create.

```
<div class="commentContent">
     <div class="comment">@comment.Comment.Text</div>
     <ul>
         <li>
             <div class="newsTime">@comment.User.FirstName @comment.User.LastName</div>
         </li>
         <li>- </li>
         <li>
             <div class="newsTime">
                 @foreach (var role in comment.CommenterRoles) {
                     if (role.Role.Equals("Authenticated") || role.Role.Equals("Administrator")) {
                                            //Don't write anything
                     } else {
                         @role.Role@:.
                     }
                 }
             </div>
         </li>
         <li>- </li>
         <li>
             <div class="newsTime">
                 @Project.Tools.TimeTool.ToTimeSinceString(comment.Comment.SubmitDateTime)
             </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr />
```

Comment: What does the ajax call return? HTML for a single comment, the entire comments pane? Nothing?

Comment: it doesn't return anything really. A bool representing wheter or not the operation was successful towards the DB. All the info I need to create the comment exists in either the ViewBag or the comment input.

Comment: Perhaps consider making it return a partial view containing the markup for a single comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very basic example of how to add comment dynamically. Whitout more information on what data is returned I cant help much more. This makes the assumption that your Action returns a partial view for that single comment.

JSFiddle containing example markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/SMbxk/

```
// This is what you would add to your success call - Assumes that your action method returns a parial view for the comment


data = "<div class=\"comment\"> Some Example </div>";

$(".commentContent").prepend(data);
```

My recomendations:

Create a partial view that displays a single comment.
Inside of your comments do a foreach loop calling the partial passing through a single comment object. i.e:

```
foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
 @Html.Partial("comment", comment);
}
```

Comment.cshtml:

This is where you place your repeated mark up.

SubmitComment action:
Return the partial Comment.cshtml with the newly added Comment

```
return View("Comment", newCommentObj);
```

This means there will be no extra data being passed around.
The other approach is to take the information posted in and add the markup yourself using the prepend (Or append, depending on your needs) Or as nayish has mentioned, use the clone but again although this is a little more manual and you'll end up managing the markup in two places instead of one. Using these methods would make maintaining it a pain in the long run.

Comment: May as well `.load()` the HTML from the ActionResult.

Comment: If its a partial that only has 1 comment in it then it would overwrite the other comments (Since im talking about it returning the markup for just one comment) If the view returned all of the comments you'd be absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is create an area in your page which is hidden and there put any elements you want to multiply and change later:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hidden" style="display: none">
     <div class="commentContent">
          <div class="comment">@comment.Comment.Text</div>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <div class="newsTime"></div>
              </li>
              <li>- </li>
              <li>
                   <div class="newsTime">
                   </div>
              </li>
              <li>- </li>
              <li>
                  <div class="newsTime">
                  </div>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

now using jquery clone this div and change the inside of the different list items and plant it wherever you want on the page.

Comment: This will work, but repeats what exists in the RAZOR View code that the OP has posted.

Comment: The RAZOR code that @wardh builds the HTML for a comment based on a Model of a comment. If he returns this for that Action, the HTML will already exist and can be inserted, ready-made to the DOM, rather than populating a template. jQuery has the `.load()` method for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load the results of an ajax call to a selector.

If you aim it at an action that returns partial view then you won't have to play with the JSON result to build the HTML to insert into the DOM using the DOM insertion functions:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-replacement/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look a this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

I think it's still beta, but it made me think about your question.